# AdMob banners with no internet connection in Android apps

Tags: google-play, admob

I've already seen questions about problems of displaying banners when the device has no internect connection. My question is one step beyond. 
You can display a custom banner or simply doesn't display anything instead. 
Let's say your app is used 90 % of times without internet connection (supposing your app does not require internet connection to work). Thus the developer would be earning only 10 % of the money. Is that right? Because I guess how it's not possible to guarantee to AdMob company that the banners in your app have been viewed the number of times your app has counted.
Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. That is 100% correct.